# swift MMDrawerController: want to change rootViewController

Tags: swift, authentication, mmdrawercontroller

I am using MMDraweController. It work perfectly. I have problem with rootViewController. When app starts it load loginViewController. So I dont want side bar menu there (loginViewController doesnt have any navigation controller). My problem is using code below the app starts from viewController, not loginViewController. How can I use login page with no side bar menu and viewController with side bar?

```
var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController

        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        var centerViewController  = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as ViewController
        //var rootViewController = centerViewController

        var leftViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SideBarMenuViewController") as SideBarMenuViewController
        var leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
        var centerSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

        centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerSideNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)


        centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView
        centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView

        window!.rootViewController = centerContainer
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: I tried to change window!.RootViewController = loginViewController but it gives me an error

Comment: yes, one minute I will put answer

Comment: Did you found any solution for your problem, can you share it, i am facing the same issue like you.

Answer (score 1):

When you load loginPageViewController just put this line of code:

```
 var appDelegate: AppDelegate =  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    appDelegate.centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.None
```

Comment: put it to viewdidload method

Comment: look at my question...you have same type of question.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944715/set-up-side-drawer-controller or storyboard postion

Comment: ya i put it in viewdidload but still it goes to viewcontroller insted of login....i just change the code with your question code ....please help me dude...have a same situation

Answer (score 1):

Too late but might help someone else...

I solved such issue by creating a function in AppDelegate.swift

```
func goToMainVC() {
    var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
    let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var centerViewController  = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as ViewController
    //var rootViewController = centerViewController

    var leftViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SideBarMenuViewController") as SideBarMenuViewController
    var leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
    var centerSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

    centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerSideNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)
    centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView
    centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView

    window!.rootViewController = centerContainer
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Then called this function after finishing from login or another ViewController like this

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.goToMainVC()
```

That's it!