# Set up side drawer controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation-drawer, uistoryboard

basically i use `MMDrawerviewController` for side drawer and my setup for storyboard prototype is like below

[image]

and my code is as successful login is

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

MenuVC *menuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuVC"];

UIViewController *centerViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC1"];


MMDrawerController *drawer = [[MMDrawerController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:centerViewController leftDrawerViewController:menuViewController];

((VC1 * )centerViewController).drawer = drawer;
menuViewController.drawer = drawer;


[drawer setRestorationIdentifier:@"MMDrawer"];
[drawer setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll];
[drawer setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];

[drawer
 setDrawerVisualStateBlock:^(MMDrawerController *drawerController, MMDrawerSide drawerSide, CGFloat percentVisible) {
     MMDrawerControllerDrawerVisualStateBlock block;
     block = [[MMExampleDrawerVisualStateManager sharedManager]
              drawerVisualStateBlockForDrawerSide:drawerSide];
     if(block){
         block(drawerController, drawerSide, percentVisible);
     }
 }];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:drawer animated:YES];
```

**Problem**
When i login and push to `vc1` it gives me back button(obviously because i am pushed through `nav1`)..and if i am trying to hide but not able to do it...don't know why.

So the question is how can i change the navigation controller after it is pushed from the other navigation controller like push with nav1 and as i get `vc1` i want to change navigation controller to `nav2` and if it is not possible then how to setup the drawer?

> Note: i am using `MMdrawerviewController` but you can suggest me any other drawer controller to get rid of this

In `appdelegate` what i do is

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController;

if (i have user data)

    navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Nav1"];

}
else
{
    navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Nav2"];
}

[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
```

So, any idea...how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my code I took away the navigation controller at all because on MMDrawer we set it programatically. Look to this code:

```
var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController

    let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var centerViewController  = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginPageViewController") as LoginPageViewController
    //var rootViewController = centerViewController

    var leftViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SideBarTableViewController") as SideBarTableViewController
    var leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
    var centerSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

    centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerSideNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftViewController)


    centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView
   // centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.None
    centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView

    window!.rootViewController = centerContainer
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

you already have navigation controller. Second Issue on the viewcontroller that comes after login view controller i set navigation bar ! So you just need to hide common navigation bar and show navigation bar that you set manually!

Answer (score 0):

One Possible approach to that, one which i normally follow, is to keep the login/signup section and the rest of the app under separate `navigation controllers`. The login section will be your initial `root view controller`. So when you want to launch into the main page after login, you can just change the root view controller to the second `navigation controller` or the `drawer-container`, depending on your case :

```
//Get instance of AppDelegate
AppDelegate *appDelegateTemp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Get the second viewController/navigationController
UIViewController* rootController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainPageHost"];

//set it as the new root
appDelegateTemp.window.rootViewController = rootController;
```

This can be done vice-versa for logout. cheers

PS : also take a look at [`SWRevealViewController`](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). Its easy to use once you get the hang of things. and can be configured using storyboard segues.

**UPDATE :** In you code above, it seems you are pushing the `drawer` containing `vc1` into `nav1`, which is the navigation controller which has the login screen.

Instead, what you can do is : instead of

> [self.navigationController pushViewController:drawer animated:YES];

you can set nav2 as the root view controller, just like you did in `appDelegate`

Comment: i have already do that...what i have is if i login successful i stored data in preference and according to that i did set up the root view...

Comment: but your login section is under the drawer controller right??

Comment: after the login...i want drawer in vc1..but also change the navigation controller

Comment: i just set the rootviewcontroller to nav2 after when login successful but not working yet